# Cannot read property variable of undefined. Where is a mistake?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I trying to get data from another site and add it to array and after that I want to use data in a select, but I get error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'locationList' of undefined

```
data() {
    return {
        locationList: [{
            text: 'Default',
            value: 'none'
        }]
    }
}
```

I run function on Created

```
created() {
    this.getLocations()
}
```

Simple function which get data from another site via fetch

```
methods: {
    getLocations: function() {
        fetch('https://www.webpagetest.org/getLocations.php?f=json')
            .then(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return response.json()
                } else {
                    throw response;
                }
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                var list = Object.entries(data.data).map(([k, v]) => ({
                    text: v.Label,
                    value: k
                }))
                this.locationList.push(list);
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            });
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake? How will be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be the context of `this` issue.

In your `getLocations()` try adding this line before the `fetch`:

`let vm = this`

then inside your `fetch` function use:

`vm.locationList.push(list);` instead of `this.locationList.push(list);`

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Or change it to arrow function

Comment: Correct, arrow function would also do the trick. Glad it worked.

Comment: There is one more way with `.bind(this)`

Answer (score 3):

If you use arrow functions instead, you don't need to create variable to access `this`. Instead, `this` from the outer context is available inside the arrow function.

```
getLocations: function() {
    fetch('https://www.webpagetest.org/getLocations.php?f=json')
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json()
            } else {
                throw response;
            }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            var list = Object.entries(data.data).map(([k, v]) => ({
                text: v.Label,
                value: k
            }))
            this.locationList.push(list);
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        });
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to write **arrow** functions. The OP was using **anonymous** functions already. Arrow functions and regular functions can both be anonymous, but when they are, the **this** keyword has a different meaning.

Comment: I corrected it. (You can edit answers after you post them in SO.)